# What is the current state of Kafka health indicator support in Spring Boot 2.7.x?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, health-check

We are using Spring Boot 2.7.x. actuator/health endpoint not returning the health status of Kafka.

It looks like Spring Boot provided this support earlier and then reverted. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/kafka/KafkaHealthIndicator.html

I don't see any auto-configured health indicators for Kafka in the latest spring boot doc. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.health.auto-configured-health-indicators

Can someone explain the background of this? Adding a Custom health indicator is the only option?

Added Kafka as dependency in our application and then validated the health status.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Health status detail is not showing the Kafka health status. We need a Kafka health status as well along with the health status detail.

Comment: There is no way to provide a health indicator that will reliably satisfy all possible conditions; for example, if transactions are being used and there are not enough in-sync replicas running for the transaction log, there is no way to determine that situation. For this reason, Boot decided not to provide one and users can provide their own instead, for their specific situation.

Comment: It was reverted https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12225

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12225 , Kafka health indicator support has been reverted from spring boot.

Below link will be helpful to add a custom health indicator for Kafka.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/springboot-kafka-health-indicator-zhifu-jin

Comment: does not work with 2.7.14 spring version