# How to check if connection to Kafka is ok?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I create a Spring-Boot app that uses Kafka.

I have the Kafka-settings in my application.properties.

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers = localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = mygrp
....
```

In the app I have components that are using it as a consumer

```
@Component
public class MyConsumer
{   
  @KafkaListener (topicPattern = "mytopic")
  public void consume (ConsumerRecord <String, MyRecord> cr, @Header 
  (KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic)
  {
    // ..
  }
}
```

and as a producer.

```
@Component
public class MyProducer 
{
    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate <String, MyRecord> kt;

    public void procude (String key, MyRecord mr)
    {
      ProducerRecord <String, LogRecord> pr = new ProducerRecord <String, MyRecord> ("abc", key, new MyRecord ("123"));
      this.kt.send (pr);
    }
 }
```

That all is working fine.

But if I start the app without having Kafka started, then I get an exception in my Javas main.

```
error creating bean with name 'xxx': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic xxx not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

During the exception the app does nothing - and it takes some time (see timeout) to get the exception.

Is there a way I can check if the Kafka init is ok by myself so I can do it at the very beginning and also do some logging??

Comment: Hi, you are looking for health check for Kafka. I successfully used them with spring boot 2. [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76324495/what-is-the-current-state-of-kafka-health-indicator-support-in-spring-boot-2-7-x) a similar question with some details.

Answer (score 1):

The `error creating bean with name 'xxx':` looks suspicious. You must not call such a heavy API like message production during application context initialization.

Regarding health check. Yes, you can do that somewhere after the `AplicationContext` is fully initialized, e.g. catching `ApplicationReadyEvent` or implementing simple `ApplicaitonRunner`. Inject there `KafkaAdmin` and call its `clusterId()` or `describeTopics()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can add logic in your application to check the availability of Kafka before attempting to use it.

1. **Check Kafka Availability:**
   Use the KafkaAdmin class provided by Spring Kafka to create an instance of KafkaAdmin, which can be used to interact with Kafka clusters. You can then use the `describeCluster()` method to check the availability of Kafka.
2. **Handle Initialization:**
   Create a method in your application to initialize Kafka. This method should check the availability of Kafka using KafkaAdmin. If Kafka is available, proceed with the initialization logic. If Kafka is not available,
   log and error message or handle the situation accordingly

Here's an example of how you can implement this logic in your Java application:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.DescribeClusterResult;
import org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaFuture;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaInitializer {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaInitializer.class);
    private static final String KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "localhost:9092";

    public static void initializeKafka() {
        Properties adminClientProps = new Properties();
        adminClientProps.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        try (AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(adminClientProps)) {
            DescribeClusterResult clusterResult = adminClient.describeCluster();
            KafkaFuture<String> clusterIdFuture = clusterResult.clusterId();
            String clusterId = clusterIdFuture.get();
            LOGGER.info("Kafka cluster ID: {}", clusterId);
            // Proceed with Kafka initialization logic
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to initialize Kafka: {}", e.getMessage());
            // Handle initialization failure
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initializeKafka();
        // Your application logic
    }
}
```

In this example, the `initializeKafka()` method checks the availability of Kafka using the `describeCluster()` method of the KafkaAdmin class. If Kafka is available, it logs an informational message with the Kafka cluster ID. If initialization fails due to Kafka unavailability or any other exception, it logs an error message with the exception details.